# flutter.io (dart) - set padding as a percentage of device width?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I set padding as a percentage of screen width in Flutter?

The problem I'm trying to solve, I initially tried to solve with AspectRatio and FractionallySizedBox, as well as different attempts with Row and Columns, but the parent is a Positioned widget with a child image. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`MediaQuery`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) by doing `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to get the screen width

Comment: this gives me error error: Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions,
when I assign the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to the padding

Comment: remove the `const` keyword before your `EdgeInset` class